# form validation keep the information

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to keep the information that you have already written even if you have an error in completing the form.Now if you have not written something correctly all the fields are cleaned and you have to start from the beginning.

This is the HTML

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="" name="registration" onsubmit="return formValidation()" >
                <h2>Register now for free!</h2>
                <label for="Fname">First name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname" placeholder="First Name">
                <label for="Lname">Last name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                <label for="email">Email :</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@email.com">
                <label for="password">Password :</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="******">
                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password :</label>
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="******">
                <label id="gender">Gender : </label>
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><span>Male</span>
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"><span>Female</span><br />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
            </form>
```

This is  the Javascript

```
function formValidation() {
    var fName = document.getElementById("Fname").value;
    var lName = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var cpass = document.getElementById("cpassword").value;

    if (fName_validation(fName, 20, 3)) {
        if (lName_validation(lName, 20, 3)) {
            if (email_validation(email)) {
                if (pass_validation(pass, 20, 6)) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function fName_validation(fName, max, min) {
        var check_name = /^[A-Za-z\s ]{2,20}$/;
        if (!fName.match(check_name)) {
            alert("First name should not be empty / length be between " + max + " to " + min);
            fName.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function lName_validation(lName, max, min) {
        var check_name = /^[A-Za-z\s ]{2,20}$/;
        if (!lName.match(check_name)) {
            alert("Last name should not be empty / length be between " + max + " to " + min);
            lName.focus();
            return ;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function email_validation(email) {
        var checkk_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        if (!email.match(checkk_email)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email!");
            email.focus();
            return ;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function pass_validation(pass, max, min) {
        var check_password = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}/;
        if (!pass.match(check_password)) {
            alert("Your password should have at least one number,one letter and should be a least 6 characters!");
            pass.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (pass !== cpass) {
            alert("Password don't match!");
            cpass.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    alert("Well Done!You successfully registered!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How are the values being cleared? There's nothing in the current code that does that. Currently, your form will submit regardless of the outcome of the validation. That is what you are seeing as the values being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

make sure each validation method should return true or false.

please change two `return ;` to `return false`

Answer (score 0):

I would **not** do this with JavaScript! Because **HTML5 does the job** for you. Therefore there are the `<input>` attributes **required** and **pattern**.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,20}" required="" />
```

The user should be informed which pattern he can use. And everything is fine.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/csg5Ltnh/)